# Is there a way to retry INSERT over DB link in Oracle, in case of connection error?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

DB procedure trying to insert in another Oracle database using DB link fails to perform the activity due to connection error. Is there a way to retry (say retry 3 times) INSERT over DB link in Oracle?

Error Text:

```
Error in INSERT in ITEM table....
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel 
ORA-02063: preceding line from HRDBLINK
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to retry (say retry 3 times) INSERT

This could be one way. Run the `INSERT` in a loop and skip the loop if at least one row is inserted, otherwise retry 3 times. One thing to remember though is that this will run insert 3 times if there were no rows inserted. You could mitigate it by checking before running your insert if that's the case.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
dblink_err EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(dblink_err, -3113);

BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tst@urdblink ( id ) VALUES ( 3 );
            EXIT WHEN SQL%rowcount > 0;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN dblink_err THEN
                dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode || ' ERROR occured: Retrying');
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```